# Magento: Adding Text and fields to the order fulfillment/invoice email or forwarding customer-facing email

Tags: html, xml, magento, magento-1.5

Pretty new to the Magento e-commerce solution. Have it up and running for a customer, and it's close to a default install, save some window dressing.

When a customer places an order, they get a nice HTML-based email. But the client is getting a text-based email that doesn't have all the information the HTML customer-based one, including a pretty crucial piece of information: the items ordered.

Our client is basically using it to sell gift cards, but when an order comes in, the invoice email only has a total of the order say, $150. They don't know from the email whether that's a single $150 gift card, three $50 gift cards, etc.

How (and where) in the Magento install would I add a line-by-line list of the order's individual products

-or-

Make it so the client gets a copied on the HTML email the customer gets (order summary).

Comment: Ok, I can answer my second part of my question after digging deeper into the Magento admin configuration:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in the Magento Admin Panel: System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email that allows you to add comma-separated email addresses. Still would like to be able to edit the invoice email the client is receiving to have all the items ordered displayed